# qt app failed to build

Tags: c++, qt

I'm developing an app in Qt/C++, the goal of this app is just to scan periodically usb ports and in case the app found a specific usb device, it's start an application.

I have used QTimer but it seems not working. different search show that Q_OBJECT is required to make it work but as soon as I add Q_OBJECT the build failed.

Here is the error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "vtable for UsbDetection", referenced from:
      UsbDetection::UsbDetection() in usbdetection.o
      UsbDetection::~UsbDetection() in usbdetection.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
```

here is the header

```
class UsbDetection : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    UsbDetection();
    ~UsbDetection();
    bool isConnected();
    QTimer *activeTimer;
    void StartAgent();

public slots:
    void ScanUSB();
};
```

here the c code of the class

```
UsbDetection::UsbDetection()
{
}

UsbDetection::~UsbDetection()
{
    activeTimer->deleteLater();
}

void UsbDetection::StartAgent() {
    activeTimer = new QTimer(0);
    activeTimer->setSingleShot(false);
    activeTimer->setInterval(1000);
    connect(activeTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(UsbDetection::ScanUSB()));
    activeTimer->start();

}

bool UsbDetection::isConnected() {
    libusb_context *context = NULL;
    libusb_device **list = NULL;
    bool DeviceConnected = false;
    int rc = 0;
    ssize_t count = 0;

    rc = libusb_init(&context);

    count = libusb_get_device_list(context, &list);
    if(count == 0) {
        return DeviceConnected;
    }
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < count; ++idx) {
            libusb_device *device = list[idx];
            libusb_device_descriptor desc = {0};
            rc = libusb_get_device_descriptor(device, &desc);
            if(rc != 0) {
                return DeviceConnected;
            }
            if(desc.idVendor == PRODUCT_ID) {
                DeviceConnected = true;
                return DeviceConnected;
            }
     }
    return DeviceConnected;
}

void UsbDetection::ScanUSB() {
    if(isConnected() == true) {
        QString agentExecutableDirPath = QApplication::applicationDirPath();
        QString fileBrowserExecutablePath = agentExecutableDirPath + "/../../../../MacOS/connect";
        QProcess *process = new QProcess();
        process->startDetached(fileBrowserExecutablePath);
    }
}
```

I don't see why the build failed.

Comment: Run `qmake` and build your project again.

Comment: @vahanco thanks it works but the timer still not start

Comment: @vahancho you need an event loop for the timer, you are not running it anywhere - actually I'm surprised you don't get any errors on that in the console, since QT usually informs about such things.

Comment: @Seb, try to set the timer connection as follows: `connect(activeTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(ScanUSB()));`

Comment: Unrelated: in scanusb(): a) you're leaking that Qprocess instance.  b) startDetached is a static method, so `process` isn't used at all